# Having trouble with Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Hi I am having trouble with getting :hover to work on CSS/HTML.
I am trying to make the image from the SideBar1/SideBar2 appear in place of the main image when the mouse is hovering over SideBar1/SideBar2 and then go back to normal once the mouse is moved.

ignore the terrible naming ;).

```css
.ClassMainImage {
  position: absolute;
  height: 66%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 19%;
  left: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#MainImageMain {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ClassMainImage1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 66%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 19%;
  left: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.ClassMainImage2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 66%;
  width: 35%;
  top: 19%;
  left: 5%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#MainImageMain1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#MainImageMain2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#SideBar1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 30%;
  left: 45%;
  top: 19%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#SideBar2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 30%;
  left: 62.5%;
  top: 19%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#SideBarYellowImage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#SideBarBlackImage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#SideBar1:hover #MainImage1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#SideBar2:hover #MainImage2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#SideBar1:hover #MainImage {
  opacity: 0;
}

#SideBar2:hover #MainImage {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainImage" class="ClassMainImage">
  <img id="MainImageMain" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtuUMJsBgCOhtTj9tIjkc_9TmcEkLKEw2CJeT7bQ2MZ1JUawnPOw" alt="Blue">
</div>

<div id="MainImage1" class="ClassMainImage1">
  <img id="MainImageMain1" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2-04tLiu3qiwynLAlNwp0tT2Q7OjhvpEj1RBx4kNWZ8PNaxqEFw" alt="Yellow">
</div>
<div id="MainImage2" class="ClassMainImage2">
  <img id="MainImageMain2" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOBJix0WxTsEgPvemyH_pMAnZc3Y1oMgDzlLFeudnRNizM7Y7LZQ" alt="Black">
</div>

<div id="SideBar1">
  <img id="SideBarYellowImage" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2-04tLiu3qiwynLAlNwp0tT2Q7OjhvpEj1RBx4kNWZ8PNaxqEFw" alt="Yellow">

</div>
<div id="SideBar2">
  <img id="SideBarBlackImage" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOBJix0WxTsEgPvemyH_pMAnZc3Y1oMgDzlLFeudnRNizM7Y7LZQ" alt="Black">

</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any Id="sidebar#", sorry for the short answer ir from my Phone, check your id's

Answer (score -1):

```css
.left,
.right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.left:hover+.right {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Something like this I guess? Just change div to your img tag.

Comment: thanks, but what I am trying to do is get "MainImage1"/"ClassMainImage1" to take the place of "MainImage"/"ClassMainImage" and for "SideBar1"/"SideBarYellowImage" to stay in it's place when ever you hover over "SideBar1"/"SideBarYellowImage".

Comment: Oh, you want to switch them? It's simple, just add .left:hover {margin-left: 50%;}

Comment: No sorry, I am trying to make it so you hover over  SideBar1 and then nothing happens to SideBar1, it stays in it's place but a image similar to the one on sidebar1 appears on MainImage.

Comment: Then you want to use javascript.

Comment: Ok i will look in to it, but i have done something similar with CSS before.